# How to sync chrome *logged in* sessions across devices?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, sync, cookies, session

Is there a way to sync not only passwords, cookies, bookmarks,but also the website logged in sessions themselves?

I'm a developer that travels a lot but does not currently have a laptop (long story), so each time I need to check my email I go into an internet cafe, log into my password manager, get my email credentials, then log into Gmail, same for Repl.it, AWS, and social media. I do this three times a day at this point which is exhausting.

Is there a way for me to input only one password and get a browser logged into all these sites already? If not, how can one build one?

Thanks in advance!